# Error using preg_relace to change url youtube?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTRPVo0d90w';
$pattern = '/http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?(.*?)v=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)(\S*)/i';
$replace = $pattern.'&w=550';
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $url);
?>
```

How to result is `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTRPVo0d90w&w=550`

Comment: What are you trying to do here exactly? Can't you just add it to the url? `$url .'&w=550'`

Answer (score 2):

You can just append using the `.` operator:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTRPVo0d90w';
$string = $url.'&w=550';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTRPVo0d90w&s=222';
    $pattern = '/v=[^&]+/i';
    preg_match($pattern, $url, $match);
    echo 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?'.$match[0].'&w=550';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't get me wrong**, I'm not looking to gain any points here, but just thought I would add to this question and include a few options. I love toying with ideas like this every once in a while.

Using [**jh314's**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18049995/1415724) idea to concatenate the strings, thought that this could be used for future use, to actually replace a string inside the video's YouTube number, should the occasion ever present itself.

Such as `$number` for instance.

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
$number = 'KTRPVo0d90w';
$string = $url.$number.'&w=550';

// Output to screen
echo $string;

echo "<br>";

// Link to video
echo "<a href=\"$string\">Click for the video</a>";

?>
```

The same could easily be done for the video's width.

Answer (score 0):

Like below?

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTRPVo0d90w';
$bit = '&w=550';
echo "${url}${bit}";
```